# Were iuvenēs expected to squander the family fortune?

Tags: roman-culture, familia, roman-republic

> Within the *familia* there are inevitable tensions between members of the various hierarchies that govern
> it: fathers and sons, men and women, slave and free. As a servant of two masters, adulescens and senex (old man), the comic slave is the point where the tensions between father and son are played out.<sup>7</sup> It is the traditional role of the paterfamilias to preserve the family fortune and of the young man to waste money in extravagant living.
> ―Fitzgerald, William: ‘Slaves and Roman Comedy’ in M. Dinter (Ed.), *The Cambridge Companion to Roman Comedy* (*Cambridge Companions to Literature*, pp. 188–199), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, pp. 189f.

This quote can be read in two ways, either as a claim that the young men of the family were expected to be living their life partying and whoring around, or that *young men in comedies* were expected to do the same. I was very surprised to come across this statement, as it goes against everything I have studied previously. My question is thus simple: Were the young men of Rome expected to squander their family’s money, or is Fitzgerald here speaking about the characters of the comedies? My hunch (based on what I have studied over the years), leans heavily on the latter being the correct interpretation of this.

Comment: Might this question go better on https://history.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I thought about this. (And I am an historian, now turning classicist.) I thought that it might be reasonable to post this here to see how the community felt about these kinds of questions. Classics, after all, is cross-disciplinary; the site is, though, named Latin SE. As you probably are aware of, there have been meta discussions on what the focus of this site should be. I would have no issue in flagging this to moved to History SE. What does the community think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to be careful with the phrase "expected to." On the one hand, it can give connotations of desire. "I expect you to do well in this position" can mean "I want you to do well" or even "I demand that you do well." You can see a boss telling his subordinate such a thing. On the other hand, it can also mean acceptance of the way things are. "I expect him to screw up" doesn't necessarily mean the speaker *wants* the "him" to screw up, but that in their estimation, he will. In this sense, the *iuvenes* fall into the latter category. Youth in general are not exactly known for financial discipline.

As to whether this is referring to comedy or real life, it is clear from the passage above and the larger context of the quote that it's referring to comedy. One, you have "comic slave" mentioned in your quote, but Fitzgerald goes on to talk about "the clever slave of comedy" and mentions Plautus.

Comedy, though, is a reflection of the tensions of the real world, and Plautus and slaves have often been brought up in such a matter. We can't read about the wasteful *iuvenes* in Roman comedy and assume that all the youth were actually like that. Instead, comedy is effective because people relate to the underlying fears embedded in it. People by and large assume that the youth will spend too much on nonsense. If one were to see a *paterfamilias* squander the family fortune, that would be unexpected. Of course that happened, but it would be tragic. If the son does it, well, "*iuvenes erunt iuvenes*" and all that.